# Amazon S3 PHP Class, can I upload a file directly to a folder in a bucket

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

To upload file into bucket root I use next code:

```
$s3->putObjectFile($logFile, $bucketName,basename($logFile), S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

but how to put file into some folder?

I've tried smth like:

```
'folderName\\'. basename($logFile)
```

but it just add "folderName\" to file name and upload it in root of bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use forward slash:

```
'forlderName/' . basename($logFile)
```

This article should explain why: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html